# Ordinal Logistic Regression in Python: Is there an equivalent to SPSS

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I am currently looking for a way to analyze a Dataframe with ordinal, nominal, continuous and binary data. The dependant variable is an ordered categorial variable (5 scale Likert). Searching through the web for a way to do that in general points me to **Ordinal Logistic Regression**.

Most of the walkthrough examples I could find are in **SPSS, which distinct between DV, Factors (Categorial) and Covariates (Continuous).** I haven't been able to find an equivalent for that in python. For OLS I was using statsmodels `sm.OLS`, but for `OrderedModel` it seems that the input is not as detailed and the summary is less complete in terms of statistical tests to prove the quality of the model compared to SPSS.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel

y = df["Ordered1"]                                                ## Dependant Variable
X = df[["Binary"] + ["Ordered2"] + ["Nominal"] + ["Continuous"]*10] ## Abstract Version of the IV

mod_log = OrderedModel(y, X, distr='logit')  

res_log = mod_log.fit(method='bfgs', disp=False)
res_log.summary()
```

Has anyone an advice what maybe different package to use (or how to make better use out of `OrderedModel` and how to integrate all the different datatypes? Also tips for the necessary tests to prove the quality of the model would be very helpful. Any help or feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: X can be specified in the same way as for OLS, (including formulas). The restriction is that X should NOT have an intercept. y is best defined as pandas Categorical, or as consecutive integers 0, 1, ...

Comment: Thank you @Josef. Meanwhile I have found several significant IV and would now like to test the parallel odds assumption (with the Brant-Test) before I proceed. But I cannot find a piece of code for that in Python. Do you know any way to test this assumption? I am also still looking for a code for pseudo-R2.

Comment: McFadden prsquared is in the results instance. Cox-Snell is not connected, but it's just https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/base/model.py#L2531

Comment: test for parallel odds assumption are not available in statsmodels (nor in official Stata AFAICS)

Comment: Thank you again @Josef. Pseudo-R2 works fine! Let's see if anyone has a hint on testing the proportional odds assumption.